# É possível ver a declaração de uma função interna do js? ex.: setInteval()

Tags: javascript, funções

Estava estudando um pouco sobre funções e gostaria de saber se é possível buscar a declaração de uma função interna em javascript assim como consigo fazer em objetos internos.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Comment: Se eu entendi, sim, mas não como você acha. Se você quer ver o trecho do código que define uma função (por exemplo, o `setInteval`), ou seja, o que é executado quando tal função é chamada, precisa procurar o código fonte da implementação de um motor JavaScript, o do Chromer é o [V8](https://v8.dev/)